# How to make this Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout

what ever I try it always ends up so the second checkbox in a row doesn't show, and I don't know how to put admob wedget on the bottom of the screen

This is what I'm aiming for, thanks ahead of time: 
[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...the trick is to use relative layout for the outermost layout and nest some linear layouts to get the check boxes to align

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_row" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_row">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="edit text"></EditText>
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/check_box_holder" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/check_box_left_col" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  android:text="CheckBox01"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  android:text="CheckBox02"></CheckBox>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/check_box_right_col" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox03" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  android:text="CheckBox03"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox04" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  android:text="CheckBox04"></CheckBox>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="button1"> </Button>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="edit text2"></EditText>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="button2"> </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_row" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#88ffffff">
        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
           android:id="@+id/ad_block" 
           android:layout_margin="1px" android:layout_width="350dip" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="58dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Very nice. Do you have an xml editor that helped generate this, or was it all manual? (If it was an editor tool, which one, please?)

Comment: Nothing special, just the eclispe Android layout editor that comes with the SDK. I mostly used the xml/text editor and then the WYSIWIG view to verify I have things lined up ok.